# How to programmatically install a root ssl certificate using java

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have programmed a webserver meant to run on the user's localhost that gets jsonp requests from a remote https page.  This architecture stems from the fact that applets are about to stop being supported by every browser and I need some sort of interface in between a smartcard and the browser.

I am planning to create a root certificate and the corresponding ssl certificate, and to start serving my jsonp endpoints using https.

In order to do so, I'd like my application to allow importing the root ssl certificate to the computer so that the browser does not complain when performing https requests to localhost.

**(TL:DR) Is it possible to programatically install a root ssl certificate using java? Using which libraries?**

Comment: What operating systems and what browsers do you target? The installation procedure is different for every OS/browser.

Comment: @Robert I am targeting Windows; Linux and Mac OSX, and every mainstream browser.

Comment: Just to make sure: The localhost server is using https and you need to add this certificate as trusted? Note that you have to generate on each computer a new certificate otherwise you end up like [Lenovo](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/02/lenovo-pcs-ship-with-man-in-the-middle-adware-that-breaks-https-connections/).

Comment: Thank you for that remark. I will indeed also have to generate a different root-certificate - certificate pair for each application instance!

Comment: Please stop using signatures in your posts.

Comment: Robert: I have answered my own question and you might find the result interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered that I shouldn't need to have any certificates installed. Taking in account the current [w3c draft](https://www.w3.org/2016/07/13-webappsec-minutes.html#item05) on my problem it seems that `http://127.0.0.1*` domains should not be considered mixed content in an otherwise safe webpage. Here is a link to the commit that added this to the draft, where one can read on [its comment](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-mixed-content/commit/349501cdaa4b4dc1e2a8aacb216ced58fd316165):

> Based on the discussion in the public-webappsec thread starting at
>   [3](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webappsec/2016Apr/0044.html), our face-to-face at [4](https://www.w3.org/2016/05/16-webappsec-minutes.html#item05), and our recent call at [1](https://www.w3.org/2016/07/13-webappsec-minutes.html#item05), this patch
>   aligns mixed content's checks with Secure Context's definition of
>   potentially trustworthy URLs.
>
> Among other things, this means that `http://127.0.0.1/` will not be
>   considered mixed content when loaded in an otherwise secure page.

I have reported this issue for Chrome...

Comment: Hey, do you have a link to the Chrome ticket?